# Keras-GPU is detected in conda environment but not in ipykernel in VSCode

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, keras

So, I have a keras model to be trained GPU and the setting for the same via keras/tensorflow support works fine. When I verify the  GPU support from keras in the bash of Linux with conda environment activated, the the GPUs are detected as shown in the commandline snippet below

```
(thesis) njoshi@zzzzz: python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
2022-05-22 18:41:16.328409: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-05-22 18:41:16.359273: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-05-22 18:41:16.359985: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:1', device_type='GPU')]
```

Although the same environment with the GPUs are not detected in jupyter notebook of VSCode.
[image]

There are two perfectly working GPUs working as shown in the pic below.
[image]

Please help me troubleshoot the actual problem which I do not seem to understand.

Comment: I reproduced your code on my vscode. I haven't meet the problem. Have you checked whether jupyter notebook use the same environment with your python? You can use "ctrl+shift+P" to change the python interpreter. You can also refer to the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_setting-up-your-environment) for more information.

Comment: Yes, it is the same environment named "thesis"

Comment: I suggets you submitting your problem and related information to github. This maybe a bug.